# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-q4jjryc_/opencv-python/

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, opencv

Anyone can help for this errors, I no idea how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have `skbuild`?

Comment: No, I need to install that??

Comment: The error message clearly says that skbuild is missing.

Comment: after import, also the same errors

Comment: Can you include your full Dockerfile? My guess is you are using Alpine Linux base image, which will require you to compile from scratch. If you use better base image, it'll just download a binary package and your life will be easier: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/